# How to make dynamic radio buttons from a csv file with proper formating?

Tags: php, html, csv

I am making a report error form for a factory but I am stuck on laying out the radio buttons properly as they have to be dynamic becuase the data is gathered from a csv file.  The csv file is as follows:

```
Issue Type,Issue Description,Issue ID,Machine
Program Issue,Incorrect sheet size for program,1,EM Machines
Program Issue,Incorrect sheet thickness for program,2,EM Machines
Program Issue,Burst and tapping is on end of program,3,EM Machines
Program Issue,Part not tooled ,4,EM Machines
Program Issue,Part falling out of sheet,5,EM Machines
Program Issue,Micro join too big on part,6,EM Machines
Program Issue,Tooled part bursting but not tapping,7,EM Machines
Program Issue,Uneven QTY of parts that have a left and right on sheet,8,EM Machines
Program Issue,Excessive QTY on sheet,9,EM Machines
Program Issue,Incorrect 'C' station selected,10,EM Machines
Program Issue,No drawing attached to file,11,EM Machines
Machine Issues,Blunt tool,12,EM Machines
Machine Issues,Damaged tool,13,EM Machines
Program Issue,No drawing attached to file,14,Pressbrake
Program Issue,No overall length indicated in drawing,15,Pressbrake
```

The only data I am really using at the moment is the Issue Description and the Machine. The reason I use these two values is because when the user clicks on a specific "Report Error" button they will be given unique options as the machines in the factory tend to have different errors. This is all dealt with in a function. Here is the function:

```
function customErr ($ID)
{
    $html = "";
    $issueReport_folder = 'document/Production System/';
    $issueReporting = $issueReport_folder.'IssueReporting.csv';

    $file_handle = fopen($issueReporting, "r");
    /*while (!feof($file_handle)) 
    {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $line_of_text[0]." ".$line_of_text[1]." ".$line_of_text[2]." ".$line_of_text[3]."<br>";
    }*/

    if ($ID == 20)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[3] == "EM Machines")
            {       
                $html .= $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 30)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[3] == "Pressbrake")
            {
                $html .= $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $html;
 }
```

The main problem I have is that I can not get the error options to go under the category title. It is easy enough to write the radio button html...

```
<label>
<input name="category" 
type="radio" 
value="<?php echo $html; ?>">
<?php echo $html; ?>
</label><br><br><br>
```

...inside the function however this means that all the radio buttons will be at the top of the form and not under the 'category' title.

The image below shows what the form looks like and where the radio buttons are meant to be. Obviously in the complete version the the radio buttons will have all the values in it.

[image]

I have heard suggestions of using an array however I am not completely sure how to implement that. I have also tried calling the function however it is either not returning properly or just doesn't work.

Here is my full code if you want (HTML at the bottom):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main_style.css">
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid white;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<script>
function close_window() {
    close();
}
</script>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include("includes/classes.php");
include("includes/classes_monitoring.php"); 
$link = open_v8_db();
$users = get_clocked_in_users();
$OperationID = @$_REQUEST['OperationID'];

$title = "";
$grayedOut = false;
$disabledInput = "";
$hiddenJobDiv = "";
$hiddenPartDiv = "";
$ID = "";
$html = "";

$jobid    = @$_REQUEST['JobID'];
$part_id  = @$_REQUEST['PartID'];
$machCode = @$_REQUEST['Machine'];

if ($OperationID == 20)
{   
    customErr($OperationID);
    $title = "Punching Machine";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 30)
{
    customErr($OperationID);
    $title = "Folding Machine";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 40 || $OperationID == 140)
{
    $title = "Powder Coating";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 50 || $OperationID == 150)
{
    $title = "Assembly";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 60 || $OperationID == 160)
{
    $title = "Inspection";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($jobid != "" && $part_id == "")
{
    $title = "Job";
}
else
{
    $title = "General";
    $grayedOut = false;
}

if ($greyedOut = true)
{
    $disabledInput = "readonly";
}

function customErr ($ID)
{
    $html = "";
    $issueReport_folder = 'document/Production System/';
    $issueReporting = $issueReport_folder.'IssueReporting.csv';

    $file_handle = fopen($issueReporting, "r");
    /*while (!feof($file_handle)) 
    {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $line_of_text[0]." ".$line_of_text[1]." ".$line_of_text[2]." ".$line_of_text[3]."<br>";
    }*/

    if ($ID == 20)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[3] == "EM Machines")
            {       
                $html .= $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 30)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[3] == "Pressbrake")
            {
                $html .= $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $html;
}

$jobErr = $partErr = $machErr = "";
$job = $part = $mach = $note = "";

if ($jobid == "")
{
    $hiddenJobDiv = "style=\"display:none;";
}
if ($part_id == "")
{
    $hiddenPartDiv = "style=\"display:none;";   
}

function test_input($data) 
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
<div class="reportForm">
    <h2>Report <u><?php echo $title; ?></u> Error</h2>
    <form action="send_form_email.php?OperationID=<?php print ($OperationID) ?>&title=<?php print ($title) ?>" method="post"> 
        <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Name:</td> 
                <td>
                <select name="users">
                <?php
                foreach($users as $key => $value){
                    echo "<option value=\"$key\">$key</option>";
                }
                ?>
                </select>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td <?php print $hiddenJobDiv ?>>Job Number:</td> <td><input type="text" name="jobid" value="<?php print ($jobid) ?>" <?php print $disabledInput ?>></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td <?php print $hiddenPartDiv ?>>Part Number:</td> <td><input type="text" name="partid" value="<?php print ($part_id) ?>" <?php print $disabledInput ?>></td>
        </tr>
           <?php if ($OperationID == 20){ ?>
             <tr>
               <td>Machine:</td> <td><input type="text" name="mach" value="<?php print ($machCode) ?>" <?php print $disabledInput ?>></td>
             <tr>
           <?php } ?>
         </table><br>
       Category:<br><br><br>
       <?php
       $html .= customErr($ID);
       ?>
       <label>
       <input name="category" 
       type="radio" 
       value="<?php echo $html; ?>">
       <?php echo $html; ?>
       </label><br><br><br>
       <?php
       /*
                        ?>
                        <label>
                        <input name="category" 
                        type="radio" 
                        value="<?php echo $line_of_text[1]; ?>">
                        <?php echo $line_of_text[1]; ?>
                        </label><br><br><br>
                        <?php
        */
        ?>
           <label>
           <input name="category" type="radio" value="Other" checked>Other
           </label><br><br><br>
       Note:<br> <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="70" placeholder="More detail... (Is there a way to recreate the error? What happened?)"></textarea>
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="userFriendly"> 
       <a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;"><input type="submit" name="close" value="Close" class="userFriendly"></a>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Summary: What I need is to have the csv file to be printed out under the 'Category' title in radio button form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The function `customErr($ID):`**

```
function customErr($ID)
{
    $html = "";
    $issueReport_folder = 'document/Production System/';
    $issueReporting = $issueReport_folder.'IssueReporting.csv';

    $file_handle = fopen($issueReporting, "r");
    /*while (!feof($file_handle))
    {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $line_of_text[0]." ".$line_of_text[1]." ".$line_of_text[2]." ".$line_of_text[3]."<br>";
    }*/

    if ($ID == 20)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[3] == "EM Machines")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 30)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[3] == "Pressbrake")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $html;
}
```

**And the category output will be:**

```
Category:<br><br><br>
        <?php
        $html = customErr($OperationID);
        foreach ($html as $oneError):?>
        <label>
            <input name="category"
                   type="radio"
                   value="<?php echo $oneError; ?>">
            <?php echo $oneError; ?>
        </label><br>
        <?endforeach;?>
        <label>
            <input name="category" type="radio" value="Other" checked>Other
        </label><br><br><br>
```

**Final form will looks like: (if your choise `$OperationID == 20` (Punching Machine) for example)**
[image]

**or if your choise `$OperationID == 30` (Folding Machine)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks dumkaaa. Not at my computer with the files at the moment. Looks promising though. Ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: Works fantastically. Thank you very much.